# Wordpress: Using OnClick() and Ajax to fire off a php function from a checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am attempting to use the onclick() function and Ajax from within a checkbox to write insert or update a record in a database.

The onclick() function properly calls the javascript code but the Ajax call never calls the PHP function to save the data.

Below is the code:

PHP:

This is the code for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="completed-'.$c.'" value = "' .$c. '" ' .$vcl_compcheck. ' ' .$vcl_compdisable. ' onclick="frontend_checklist_checkbox_changed(' .$c. ')">
```

Here is the rest of the PHP code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_fc_checkbox_changed', array('Frontend_Checklist', 'changedAjax'));



public static function add_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('frontend-checklist', plugins_url('frontend-checklist.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));

    wp_localize_script( 'frontend-checklist', 'frontendChecklist', 
        array( 
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        )
    );
}





public static function changedAjax() {
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_ID == 0) die;


        $ca = (int)$_POST('fc_itemID');
        $fc_completed = "on";

        $casql = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT completed from wp_fc_vendorlist WHERE fc_vendorID = ' .$user_ID. ' and fc_itemID = ' .$ca. ' ORDER BY fc_itemID ASC' );
        $cachk = $wpdb->get_row($vsql, ARRAY_A);
        $table_name = 'wp_fc_vendorlist';

    if($cachk =='') {
        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_name (fc_itemID, fc_vendorID, completed) VALUES ('$ca', '$user_ID', '$fc_completed')"  );
    } else {
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET completed= $fc_completed WHERE fc_vendorID=$userid and vc_itemID = $ca"));
    }       

    output();

    die;
}
```

and finally, this is the javascript code:

```
function frontend_checklist_checkbox_changed(fc_listID) {
    var checkbox;
    var fc_listID;

        checkbox = jQuery('#completed-' + fc_listID);
        if (checkbox && checkbox.prop('checked')) {
              var data = { action: 'fc_checkbox_changed', fc_listID: fc_listID};
              jQuery.post(frontendChecklist.ajaxurl, data);
        alert("The javascript funciton has been initiated ");
        }
}
```

the Alert box fires in the javascript code, so I know it is getting to that point, but it never goes beyond that into calling the changedAjax() function in PHP.

I know I'm missing something simple, I just can't figure out what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're sending `fc_listID` and trying to get `fc_itemID` in admin ajax. You should also use square brackets: `$_POST['fc_listID']`

Comment: @diggy

Good catch on the fc_listID vs fc_itemID ... I made that change as well as adding the square brackets (as you suggested).  

When I add the square brackets it breaks the whole site (not just that page, but the whole site).  It just goes white and nothing loads.

The call back to the PHP function still does not (seemingly) work however.

Comment: Enable WP_DEBUG to see what goes wrong. codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: I think I located the problem, just not the solution (yet).

Using Chrome and the developer tools (network tab).  I found this when clicking on the checkbox:

 POST http://new.chocolatefest.com/site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)jquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 sendjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.extend.ajaxjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.(anonymous function)frontend-checklist.js?ver=4.0.1:8 frontend_checklist_checkbox_changed(index):273 onclick

Comment: What I further noticed is that your `$wpdb->prepare` syntax is wrong, check the Codex entry for `$wpdb`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @diggy  I did catch the syntax issue in the prepare statement at some point in the past couple hours.  I did eventually get the code working after I cleaned up all of my syntax mistakes (there were a number of them that I didn't catch).  The WP_DEBUG helped tremendously.

Thanks for all of your assistance with this issue.